# "this" in object methods vs "this" in event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

**Edit**
The answers pointed out that keyword `this` is used in jQuery just as in any JavaScript code. That is, an object method receives the object itself as `this`, this is what happens with `$.fn` functions (they are called on jQuery objects). Event handler functions are callback functions, they are not object methods, and it is the caller that decides what `this` will refer to inside the function. It normally references a DOM element.

**Original question**

The differece between `this` and `$(this)` is often explained as `this` references a **DOM object**, while `$(this)` references a **jQuery object** (a DOM element with a jQuery wrapper around it).
In the following example, the handler function is passed `this` as a DOM element, and by wrapping it in `$()` we make a jQuery object from it, thus we can use on it the functions living in the `$.fn` namespace.

```
$('div').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
});
```

However, I have just come across this explanation on learn.jquery.com:

**[Plugins | jQuery learning center](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)**

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
this.css( "color", "green" );
};
$("a").greenify(); // makes all the links green

// Explanation provided by the author of the article:
// "Notice that to use css(), another method, we use this, not $( this ).
//  This is because our greenify function is a part of the same object as css()."
```

Does it mean that `this` references a DOM object when passed to an event handler function, but refers to a jQuery object when passed into a jQuery object method?
In fact, it makes sense, since the method is called on a jQuery object, thus it is logical to pass it a jQuery object.

Comment: In JavaScript, doing `object.myMethod()` automatically makes `object` the value of `this` inside `.myMethod()`. So `$("a").greenify()` makes the jQuery object the value of `this` in `.greenify()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "this" identifier has nothing to do with jQuery, it's an integral part of javascript.

You can check this link which provides a detailed explanation of the "this"-keyword: http://www.devign.me/javascript-this-keyword/

Comment: Thanks for this enlightement, it seems while learning about the "role" of "this" in jQuery, I forgot about its ultimate meaning in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

In a jQuery plugin method `this` is already the jQuery object.  Thus, you can use jQuery methods directly on `this`.

This has nothing to do with event handlers.  It's because when a method is called on an object (a jQuery object in this case), javascript sets `this` to point to the object.  So, since the object in this case is a jQuery object, that's what `this` is.

An event handler callback function is not a method call so it works differently - it's a callback and the caller of the callback decides what to set `this` to using either `.call()` or `.apply()`.  For most event handler callbacks the code specifically decides to set `this` to the DOM object that triggered the event.

Comment: It has helped a lot that you pointed out that event handlers are callback functions, not methods on jQuery objects. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

That's because in your `greenify` plugin, there is no callback involved, no event handler.

It is called by

```
$("a").greenify();
```

which means that `this`, inside the function, is the receiver, that is `$("a")`, just like `this`, in `b` when you execute `a.b();` is `a`.

Answer (score 1):

`.greenify` is invoked as a method on the `jQuery` instance. If you look in the jQuery source, you'll find

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
  // All the goodies...
```

which shows that your understanding is correct.